# How do I convert a XAML brush into a Direct2D brush?

Tags: xaml, direct2d, microsoft-metro

I am working on a Metro Style App.  In Metro, you can [mix XAML and DirectX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh825871.aspx).  I am creating a XAML user control that uses a shared surface to render some content in Direct2D.  I want to be able to specify a brush in XAML that I can use to fill a geometry in Direct2D.

I think what I need to be able to do is convert a [Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::Brush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.brush.aspx) into an [ID2D1Brush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371173%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Direct2D interfaces have a close correspondence to the XAML classes. However, there are several things you won't be able to copy or emulate with just an `ID2D1Brush`, such as `Transform` vs. `RelativeTransform`. Things get much worse if you look at things like `TileBrush` or `LinearGradientBrush.MappingMode`. You'd need to create your own wrapper for `ID2D1RenderTarget` which took into account more factors than are generally available otherwise.

Direct2D is a low level drawing API, whereas the XAML classes are part of a larger presentation/UI framework (it's cut-down WPF/Silverlight). If you're not worried about the properties that can't be copied or emulated, then just create some static utility methods for converting between the two.